# Stop Backspace When Modal Displayed In Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a modal which is displaye on click of a button (works fine).  I have managed to stop it closing when clicking outside of it and also using the 'Esc' key but the issue i'm haing is that when the modal is open and the user hits the 'Delete (Backspace)' key on the keyboard, my modal stays displayed (as expected) but the screen in the background changes to the previous one and i want to stop this.

All my code is shown below for my modal

```
vm.addTransfersIn = function (ev) {
    vm.moneyindialogservice.setcurrentdialogtype('Transfer', 'Add');
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'MoneyInDialogController',
        templateUrl: 'src/moneyin/components/moneyin.dialog.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
        escapeToClose: false
    })
    .then(function (answer) {
        vm.status = answer;
    }, function () {
        vm.status = 'Cancel';
    });
};
```

Comment: You need to listen to keyup events globally on the document, track the modal state in a variable, and preventDefault / return false from the keyup event handler when keycode is backspace and modal sate is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hostListner bound to a keyboard event.  Then handle the output.  To prevent the default functionality occuring, call `event.preventDefault()`

```
    @HostListener("document:keyup", ["$event"])
    handleKeyup(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: on the keyup this didn't work for me. But on the keydown it did

Comment: btw. I did also add an extra condition so backspace did still work on input and textarea: document.activeElement != null && ['TEXTAREA','INPUT'].indexOf(document.activeElement.nodeName) == -1